# How to show a nonlinear differential equation has no real solutions (or does it?)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

The equation for $y(x)$ is

$$
a=b(1-x^2)(1+y'^2)+y \qquad,\quad y(0)=0
$$

Where $a=y(1)$, $b >0$, and we may consider $0 \leq x \leq 1$. The solution is expected to be continuous but not necessarily differentiable at $x=0$.

**Question** I conjecture that there are no real, monotonically increasing solutions, but am unable to demonstrate this. How to do so? The conjecture may be incorrect.

I've played around with it, and asked Mathematica with no success. I've stared at the vector plot of $(1,y')$ in the $x-y$ plane. I've started to construct a perturbation series solution, but it's difficult to have faith in it viz. possible nonexistence of solutions.

**Background** The equation comes from [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/678661/what-shape-must-a-bowl-be-to-have-a-ball-rolling-in-the-bowl-execute-perfect-si) on physics stackexchange. $y(x)$ is the inner surface of a bowl in which a particle slides without friction, such that (in my interpretation of the question) the $x$ projection of the motion is simple harmonic. The constant $a$ is the (conserved) energy, and $b=\omega^2/2$, where $\omega$ is the angular frequency of oscillation of $x(t)$.

If you'd like more information please ask in a comment!

Comment: Your equation can be transformed to an Abel equation via the substitutions $x=\sin(\sqrt b\xi)$, $y=a-b\cos(\sqrt b\xi)^2-1/u^2.$ The solution consists of an implicit equation containing the Bessel functions in “Construction of Exact Parametric or Closed Form Solutions of Some Unsolvable Classes of Nonlinear ODEs (Abel’s Nonlinear ODEs of the First Kind and Relative Degenerate Equations)”.

Comment: @Eli Thank you! How did you figure out those substitutions?

Comment: I have seen before that $(y’)^2+f(x)y=g(x)$ can be transformed to an Abel equation. I then just tried some substitutions to find which led to an Abel equation.

Comment: You can also transform it to an Abel equation of the second kind via the transformation $x=\sin(\sqrt b\xi)$, $y=a-b\cos(\sqrt b\xi)-u^2$, which has a solution as well if the first one isn’t working out, though it’s a bit more involved.

Comment: @Eli Thank you. It seems that after all the transforms, it is difficult to see if a solution with the required properties exists? Unless I miss something?